# How does this project home page lands up when we create an mvc project in visual studio? Where is this code resides?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, vs-extensibility, project-template

Where is this html markup (I guess it is html, it can be something else too) code is written and how does this html is shown as a tab whenever the project is loaded.?

[image]

Comment: You're most likely going to have to go sifting through all the VS files on your machine to find whatever view is rendered there. I doubt anyone on this site actually knows the exact location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This html page is under;

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\YourVersion\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web
>   Tools\Project\Overview

There are four overview page depending your project type.
Thanks

Comment: How to create a custom overview page and where to hook it so that it land up when we load the project template.

Comment: Well, i really don't know, never tried. you could probably ask and have an answer in visual studio board on msdn. sorry, couldn't help out ya.